# Does JBehave based negative-scenarios grow exponentially?

Tags: testing, jbehave, maintainability, scenarios

In behavior based testing, it looks like the number of error scenarios grow exponentially.

As per Aslak Hellesøy, [BDD was created](https://cucumber.io/blog/2014/03/03/the-worlds-most-misunderstood-collaboration-tool) to combine automated acceptance tests, functional requirements and software documentation.

> In 2003 I became part of a small clique of people from the XP community who were exploring better ways to do TDD. Dan North named this BDD. The idea was to combine automated acceptance tests, functional requirements and software documentation into one format that would be understandable by non-technical people as well as testing tools.

Software development teams use JBehave as a tool for BDD testing (thanks to [Dan North](https://dannorth.net/introducing-bdd/)).

As there can be a lot of possible negative options; it looks like the number of negative scenarios in a JBehave test suite can grow a lot in numbers. Time taken to run test suite as well as to modify the product increases with these kind of growing scenarios. Specially, I feel that it is becoming hard to maintain as a documentation of the product.

I am not exactly sure whether this is an abuse of BDD/JBehave concepts due to misunderstandings from different teams; or may be that is the way it should be.

## Let me explain this concern with an example.

Say an application has a behavior to order an item via a REST service.

```
PUT /order
{ 
    // JSON body with 3 mandatory parameters and 2 optional parameters
}
```

## Happy scenario

1. Invoke REST endpoint with correct values for all 3 mandatory parameters
2. Invoke REST endpoint with correct values for all 5 parameters

## Negative scenarios

There are a lot of negative scenarios that we can come up with.

### Input value based scenarios

1. Mandatory parameter 1 is set to null, with correct values for other two mandatory parameters (3 possible scenarios with each mandatory parameter)
2. Mandatory parameter 1 is set to empty, with correct values for other two mandatory parameters (3 possible scenarios with each mandatory parameter)
3. Mandatory parameter 1 is set to a value in invalid format, with correct values for other two mandatory parameters (3 possible scenarios with each mandatory parameter)
4. Mandatory parameter 1 & 2 are set to null, with correct value for other mandatory parameter (2 possible scenarios)

Likewise, we can write 3^3 scenarios just for those three parameters; which grows exponentially with the number of parameters.

Then we can combine, optional parameters also into the equation and come up with more scenarios (say optional parameter with null, empty and invalid-format values).

### Payment ability based scenarios

Based on available money, there will be scenarios.

### Delivery location based scenarios

Based on delivery possibilities, there will be scenarios.

## Question/Concern

I would like to learn more on whether all these negative scenarios (+more) should be part of JBehave based test suite? If that is the case, any advice/thoughts on how to make it more maintainable?

Comment: There is a related question which discusses about not covering all the permutations. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570169/how-do-we-handle-minor-permutations-of-bdd-scenarios

Answer (score 0):

It helps a lot to know what the tested application does internally in its own validation processes, specifically the order of validation.

In a simplified example of three required parameters, you really only need three scenarios: one for each parameter.  If you know that the application will fail if parameter one is invalid, you don't need to check that again when you test parameter two in another scenario since the second parameter would never be validated upon failure of the first, so instead of three times three, you simply have three:

1) invalid, valid, valid.
2) valid, invalid, valid.
3) valid, valid, invalid.

That is, unless, the application DOES check all three parameters and reports accordingly that one or more parameters were invalid.  Speaking as a developer who now does automation, I can tell you that unless I thought multiple invalid parameters were a high probability, I would only check parameters one at a time and fail out with an error upon the first invalid parameter.  Having written accounting software, there were times where it was logical to validate all parameters and report accordingly, but that was the exception rather than the rule.  If you know what the application is checking, and in what order, you can write better test scripts, but I realize that is not always possible.

There is still the question of the seemingly limitless kinds of invalid data, so even in my simplified example, you could still have lots of tests, but in that situation it can be dealt-with using parameters of invalid values.  You could still limit it to just three scenarios, each having any number of invalid parameters to test.

I hope I understood your question correctly and offered some useful information.

Comment: Thanks for initiating an answer. As scenarios are written prior to implementation, we hardly can assume much; but 3 scenarios (null, empty, invalid) per parameter will fit; for 10 parameters webservice it will be 30 scenarios. From a testing point of view, should the rest of the permutations (3^10) be ignored or covered with some other tests? As BDD test report will be the feature document of the product to be shared with customers, I am wandering whether too much negative cases (30 for this 1 service) is correct? I am wandering whether this is correct use of JBehave/BDD?